# issue with polling json and showing overlay

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I am trying to execute the code and I am getting the below error.
Please let me know what could be the issue.

**Uncaught ReferenceError: poll is not defined**

Thanks.

**CSS :**

```
#overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
  <div id="overlay">
        <div class="note note-warning" id="MyDiv" style="display:none">
            <div class="block-warning">
                <h4 class="block"> <i class="demo-icon icon-attention-1 fa"></i> Alert! Upgrade </h4>
                <p>In progress.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        (function poll() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "cgi",
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("polling"+data);
                        if(data.state.is_running === false){
                            console.log("stop polling");
                            $("#overlay").show();
                            $("#commUpgradeAlertDiv").show();
                        }
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    complete: poll,
                    timeout: 2000
                })
            }, 50000);
        })();

        initPage();
    }
```

Comment: Works just fine for me -> https://jsfiddle.net/b88yu67s/

Comment: how to see the result in the above link . It is not visible for me

Comment: You open the console (F12)

Comment: Myself also it worked fine initially then later I am seeing the error message ..

Comment: Looks like the response is fast .Hence the call back function is shown as undefined